# Racket change button coordinates

Tags: button, racket

I have a button in a frame and when I change the `vert-margin` and `horiz-margin` in the code the button doesn't change it's location but rather the frame gets smaller or larger.

This is the code:

```
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame% [label "GUI BUILDER"]
                      [width 300]
                      [height 400]
                      [style '(no-resize-border)]))

(send frame show #t)

(define msg (new message% [parent frame]
                          [label "Text"]))

(new button% [parent frame]
             [label "Generate button code"]
             [vert-margin 200]   
             [horiz-margin 480]
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                         (send msg set-label "Changed"))])
```

Please give code examples, I wrote this and it doesn't work:

```
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame% [label "GUI BUILDER"]
                          [width 700]
                          [height 700]))

(send frame show #t)

(define coloana (new vertical-panel% [parent frame]))

(define cub1 (new horizontal-panel% [parent coloana]
                                    [min-height 150]))

(define cub2 (new horizontal-panel% [parent coloana]
                                    [min-height 50]))

(define cub3 (new horizontal-panel% [parent cub2]
                                    [min-width 50]))

(define buton (new button% [parent cub1]
                           [label "Generate button code"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `frame%` has as default a stretchable width and height.
Rather than using a margins to place the button at a specific location,
I suggest placing empty panel at the top and to the left of the button.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame
  (new frame% [label "GUI BUILDER"]
       [width 300]
       [height 400]
       [style '(no-resize-border)]))

(define row1
  (new horizontal-panel%
       [parent frame]
       [min-width   300]
       [min-height   50]
       [style       '(border)]
       [stretchable-height #f]))

(define row2
  (new horizontal-panel%
       [parent frame]
       [stretchable-height #f]))

(define row3
  (new horizontal-panel%
       [parent frame]
       [style '(border)]
       [stretchable-height #t]))

(define col-2-1              ; row 2 column1
  (new vertical-panel%
       [parent row2]
       [min-width 100]
       [style '(border)]
       [stretchable-height #t]))

(new message% [parent row1]    [label "row1"])
(new message% [parent col-2-1] [label "col-2-1"])
(new message% [parent row3]    [label "row3"])

(define button-msg (new message% [parent row1] [label "Text                   "]))

(define button (new button%
                    [parent       row2]
                    [label        "Click"]
                    [vert-margin  0]   
                    [horiz-margin 0]
                    [style        '(border)]
                    [callback     (λ (button event)
                                    (send button-msg set-label "Changed"))]))

(send frame show #t)
```

[image: The Frame]

Comment: Isn't there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I don't know. I have a feeling that there ought to be a container where you can simply use coordinates to place the containees. If no-one answers here, do ask the racket mailing list.

Comment: So, I should make two panels one at left and one on top of the button and then add BOTH? as parents to the button to create a margin from them? How do I even add two panels as parents for a button?

Comment: The idea is to make two rows in the frame. In the first two you place a horizontal panel whose height will determine the y-placement of the button. In the second row you place a horizontal panel first then the button. The width of the horizontal panel will determine the x-placement of the button.

Comment: So 1. make a frame. 2. Make a vertical-panel to hold the rows. 3. Place the filler panels in the vertical-panel.

Comment: By width and height you mean min-width and min-heigth?

Comment: The borders are meant to be a help while developing - remove them when done.